# React Native Require cycles are allowed warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, circular-dependency

I am working on some **React Native** project. If you work with react native or react before, you know that even in the middle-size projects, imports increase dramatically. Due to that, I use the technique which is creating index.js/ts and import a file from the one reference. Everything was quite perfect until upgrading the react version. When I had upgraded the version of the project, the project started to show me a warning message as you can see below.

[image]

But the thing is, I made this cycling dependency on purpose. I don't know how can I fix the thing by continuing to make the all imports together.

here is my Plugings/index.ts file;

[image]

and here is my Plugins/Contact.ts file;

[image]

**PS:** I know that the solution by making import directly, which means not importing from index.ts file.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Ronald Unfortunately, not. I'd decided to ignore warnings and continued :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try import your `Localization` from `'./Localization'` at `Contact.ts`

And you could work as what in index do in `Contact.ts`, and then you will not import

`index` at `Contact.ts` to disconnect the chicken-egg problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I thought that. But I want to make `barrel exporting` to make the imports more clear. Due to that, I wanted to ask from here. Do you have any other idea to fix the issue while still using `barrel export`?